# Cannot refer to non-final variable inside an inner class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have a `CountDownTimer` inside each row in a `ListView`. The only place I can have my `onClick` methods for the button in each row, is in the `CustomListAdapter`. But I can't refer to the `TextView` where the time left should be displayed. I get this error:

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable holder inside an inner class
>   defined in a different method

I have tried setting the holder to final, but then i get this error:

> The final local variable holder cannot be assigned. It must be blank
>   and not using a compound assignment

This is my code:

```
    public class CustomTimerRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < TimerRow > {

      Context context;
      int height;

      public CustomTimerRowAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List < TimerRow > items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        // Height of screen from not Activity subclass
        height = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
      }

      /* private view holder class */
      private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTimer;
        TextView txtName;
        Button bStartStop;
      }


      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        final TimerRow rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
          .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.timer_row, null);
          holder = new ViewHolder();
          // make layout params
          holder.txtTimer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimes);
          holder.txtTimer.getLayoutParams().height = height / 10;
          holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
          holder.txtName.getLayoutParams().height = height / 10;
          holder.bStartStop = (Button) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.bStartStopTimer);
          holder.bStartStop.getLayoutParams().height = height / 10;

          convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtName.setText(rowItem.getName());

        holder.bStartStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          final ViewHolder temp = new ViewHolder();@
          Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

              public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // THIS IS WHERE I CANNOT REFER TO THE NON-FINAL VARIABLE
                holder.txtTimer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
              }

              public void onFinish() {
                holder.txtTimer.setText("done!");
              }
            }.start();

          }
        });
        return convertView;
      }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You could implement the `OnClickListener` in your outer class and get rid of the inner class.  Then you can set it like: `holder.bStartStop.setOnClickListner(this)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

`final ViewHolder holder;`

ie don't assign it to null initially.

Comment: Any reason for the -1?

Comment: The code as written could not assign to that variable and make it `final`

Comment: @AndyBrown Are you referring to the fact that it can be assigned in either if/else if block? If so, that's not an issue as long as the compiler knows it's guaranteed to be assigned a value, and only once. Try it out :).

Comment: I don't agree, `final` allows to set the variable just once. In the original code he is initializing to `null`, but his code doesn't, so there is just one initialization in each case of `if`. I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure it works.

Comment: @ajacian81 agree to you on your comment, it will work as long as compiler confirms that it will be assigned only once.

Comment: I missed that you weren't assigning null to it. Can't remove downvote unless you edit your answer - gah.

Comment: Yes, if OP makes it Final and do not assign it to NULL, it should work. +1 to your answer.@ajacian81

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making `holder` final use `v.getParent()` for accessing TextView on Button click like:

```
holder.bStartStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             View parent = (View)v.getParent();
             final TextView txtTimer = parent.findViewById(R.id.tvTimes);
             //... your code here...
        }
    });
```

Use `txtTimer` in `onTick` and `onFinish` for updating TextView text.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `ViewHolder holder` as class variable. Got it? No! look  below.

your getView will look like below

```
    private ViewHolder holder;

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         holder = null;
```

Comment: This will open it up to errors.  The holder in the class variable might not be the same reference as the one in the click listener.

Comment: Are you serious?  you are marking it Null each time in getView method, that too in first line, it does not matter what reference it has.

Comment: Yes I'm serious. Imagine there are 3 views getting created. View1, view2, view3 are created in that order. Now, your class variable holder will reference view3. However, what happens if view1 is clicked?

Comment: As for marking it as null, when you mark a variable as final you are in essence passing the value of that variable to the onClickListener as it was at that moment in time (or at that moment in the stack to be more exact).

Comment: I hope you are kidding!! You need to check your facts dude.

Comment: I'm honestly not trying to be confrontational, but try it out. It's prone to errors.

Comment: OK, I will try it out then, Cheers!!